# Using Dynamic Foreground with LinearGradientBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, button, linear-gradients

I'm working on a WPF application for my first time

I have a button that when clicked on will change its foreground color.
I felt regular colors are boring so I did some Linear Gradients to make it look better.

on C# I wrote.
        // Here I create a Linear Gradient bush, a Collection of gradient stops, and the gradient stops I need and a brushconverter to get color codes #Fxxxx into color

```
        BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
        public LinearGradientBrush MetallicBlue= new LinearGradientBrush();
        public GradientStopCollection BlueG = new GradientStopCollection();
        public GradientStop BGS1 = new GradientStop();
        public GradientStop BGS2 = new GradientStop();
        public GradientStop BGS3 = new GradientStop();
        public GradientStop BGS4 = new GradientStop();
```

// Then I define each gradient stop and add it to the  GradientStop Collection

```
            BGS1.Color = (Color)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF094AAD");
            BGS1.Offset = 0.244;
            BGS2.Color = (Color)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF0745AA");
            BGS2.Offset = 0.988;
            BGS3.Color = (Color)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF286ED1");
            BGS3.Offset = 0.5;
            BGS4.Color = (Color)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF094AAD");
            BGS4.Offset = 0.076;
            BlueG.Add(BGS1);
            BlueG.Add(BGS2);
            BlueG.Add(BGS3);
            BlueG.Add(BGS4);
```

// Here I set my Metallic Blue with Properties

```
MetallicBlue.StartPoint = new Point(0.5, 0);
MetallicBlue.EndPoint = new Point(0.5, 1);
MetallicBlue.GradientStops = BlueG;
```

On my click event when I set the color foreground it changes to blank! Text disappears.

```
textBlock.Foreground = MetallicBlue;
```

Can anyone help me out.
I want to implement this on many buttons but It does not quite work.
what am I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `BrushConverter` returns a `Brush`. You should use a `ColorConverter`. This works fine for me:

```
ColorConverter cc = new ColorConverter();
LinearGradientBrush MetallicBlue = new LinearGradientBrush();
GradientStopCollection BlueG = new GradientStopCollection();
GradientStop BGS1 = new GradientStop();
GradientStop BGS2 = new GradientStop();
GradientStop BGS3 = new GradientStop();
GradientStop BGS4 = new GradientStop();

BGS1.Color = (Color)cc.ConvertFrom("#FF094AAD");
BGS1.Offset = 0.244;
BGS2.Color = (Color)cc.ConvertFrom("#FF0745AA");
BGS2.Offset = 0.988;
BGS3.Color = (Color)cc.ConvertFrom("#FF286ED1");
BGS3.Offset = 0.5;
BGS4.Color = (Color)cc.ConvertFrom("#FF094AAD");
BGS4.Offset = 0.076;
BGS4.Offset = 0.076;
BlueG.Add(BGS1);
BlueG.Add(BGS2);
BlueG.Add(BGS3);
BlueG.Add(BGS4);

MetallicBlue.StartPoint = new Point(0.5, 0);
MetallicBlue.EndPoint = new Point(0.5, 1);
MetallicBlue.GradientStops = BlueG;

textBlock.Foreground = MetallicBlue;
textBlock.Text = "Sample";
textBlock.FontSize = 40;
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed!